# Workbox Cache First not caching properly

Tags: workbox

I am trying to build a Cache First strategy with workbox on a React + NextJS app, but i am facing a problem...
I have the following rule:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/.*\/uploads|.*\/arquivos.*/'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'cache-first',
  })
);
```

Looking at workbox log a got the following messages:

[Router responding to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs5JE.png)

and

[Using Cache First to respond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJgUb.png)

But nothing gets cached as can be seen on:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY8lb.png)

If I change the strategy from **CacheFirst** to **NetworkFirst** the files get cached and everything works as expected.
Does anyone knows any issue related to that on workbox? or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem, cache first doesn't work with opaque responses, we have to use StaleWhileRevalidate in these cases, more info on:

https://tpiros.dev/blog/what-is-an-opaque-response/