# Workbox cachefirst network request error with Giphy

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using the following strategy to cache images:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|webp|gif)/,
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    "cacheName": "images",
    plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
          maxEntries: 60, 
          maxAgeSeconds: 2592000, 
          purgeOnQuotaError: false})]
}), 'GET');
```

I'm not defining any other particular strategies.

When I try it in an `index.html` containing a Gif hosted by Giphy:

```
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7baWfTjfHGLZc3e/giphy.gif"/>
```

Worbox do seeems to cache properly as long as I'm **online**

> Using CacheFirst to respond to 'https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7baWfTjfHGLZc3e/giphy.gif'

If I disable my wifi and try to refresh **offline** my page I hit the following **errors**:

> workbox Network request for 'https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7baWfTjfHGLZc3e/giphy.gif' threw an error. TypeError: Failed to fetch
>
> Uncaught (in promise) no-response: The strategy could not generate a response for 'https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7baWfTjfHGLZc3e/giphy.gif'. The underlying error is TypeError: Failed to fetch.
>       at CacheFirst.makeRequest (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-strategies.dev.js:180:15)
>
> GET https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7baWfTjfHGLZc3e/giphy.gif net::ERR_FAILED

Therefore am I missing something? Should I configure something more to be able to cache Giphy gifs? Or is it actually a bug? Or something which can't be solved?

Any help appreciated, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is a duplicate of [Workbox Cache First not caching properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039433/workbox-cache-first-not-caching-properly)

The answer is the one provided by Diego H Ferraz in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040270/5404186